# Disabling webpack and source code view on angular

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I have been working on an angular 4 project picked up from someone. I then realized that Typescripts source code could be viewed in "source" from inspector on chrome under webpack. I have searched around on how I can disable this to no avail. I have tried upgrading the angular cli, but it is not making the project run again.

[image: Source code showing on chrome]

I ran `ng build --prod` and I get this

> An old CLI configuration has been detected, which needs to be updated
>   to the latest version.
>
> Please run the following command to update this workspace:   ng update
>   @angular/cli --migrate-only --from=1

after upgrade of cli

Without upgrade, `ng build --prod` shows

> ERROR in ./src/main.ts Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in
>   '/home/rtm/repos/TNF/identity-ui/src'  @ ./src/main.ts 3:0-74  @ multi
>   ./src/main.ts

Running `ng -v` I get

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.0-rc.4
Node: 8.9.4
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 4.1.0
... common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms, http
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, platform-server
... router, tsc-wrapped

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.5.6
@angular-devkit/core         0.5.6
@angular-devkit/schematics   0.5.6
@angular/cli                 6.0.0-rc.4
@ngtools/json-schema         1.1.0
@schematics/angular          0.5.6
@schematics/update           0.5.6
rxjs                         5.4.3
typescript                   2.1.5
```

Comment: Hi, I had this same problem with my project a while ago... I solved it by upgrading to @angular/cli@6.1.2 and setting the value of "architect.build.configurations.production.sourceMap" to true inside the angular.json file.

If you are having trouble upgrading to this version you probably should check out the breaking changes in the angular/cli changelog

Comment: I also switched to this starter when I solved my issue. https://github.com/angular/universal-starter but it is quite a bit of work to migrate to

Comment: you might be able to fix the problem without upgrading angular/cli. if you could show me what your angular.json (or angular-cli.json) file looks like I might be able to help

Comment: I have done that @LukasSorensen

Comment: After upgrading to 6.1.2 and I do ng build --prod, I get

Comment: Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from "/Users/taymi/Documents/Website Projects/Angular Projects/ALATwebMain".
Error: Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from "/Users/taymi/Documents/Website Projects/Angular Projects/ALATwebMain".
    at Object.resolve (/Users/taymi/Documents/Website Projects/Angular Projects/ALATwebMain/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node/resolve.js:141:11)
    at Observable.rxjs_1.Observable [as _subscribe] (/Users/taymi/Documents/Website Projects/Angular Projects/ALATwebMain/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/src/architec

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179417/discussion-between-temi-topsy-bello-and-lukas-sorensen).